# Anyway to log information from a UDF in Databricks-spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I am creating some scala UDFs to process data in a Dataframe, and am wondering if it is possible to log information within a UDF? Any examples on how to do this?

Comment: you can use any logger (e.g. log4j) or even just `println`, but all these lines will end up in the executors log and are not visible from the driver process